# EADDRINUSE when nodemon app.js --ignore test/

Tags: node.js, nodemon

How to use [ignore](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files) option in `nodemon` for preventing `nodemon` to reload `node.js` site when something changed in test folder.

I tried this way:

```
nodemon app.js  -e iced,json --ignore test/
```

But it gives me strange error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
  at listen (net.js:1064:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1132:5)
```

Although the same script without `--ignore` works good:

```
nodemon app.js  -e iced,json
```

and run the site as expected.

Comment: If it really works without the option and the port isn't actually in use, I would say this could be a bug in `nodemon`.

Comment: Sadly I can't replicate that.

Comment: I'm the author of nodemon. I'd recommend opening an issue on http://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues and include the full output from:

nodemon app.js  -e iced,json --ignore test/ --dump
This will show the configuration of nodemon when the app is running (I assume app.js is just a simple http server).